# regex in R: Split strings and extract numbers

Tags: r, regex

I'm dealing with strings like (inside quotation marks):

`"something new * -2 5 4 else"` or "something new     -2 5 6 other"

I want to get everything after new, e.g., for string 1: `* -2 5 4`; and for string 2: `-2, 5, 6`

### there might be multiple space in strings, e.g., string 2, between `new` and `-2`

Update: thanks for the answers! I'm trying to get each number/* separately. For example, *, -2, 5 as separately elements. I tried `strsplit` but sometimes my strings have additional space in between numbers, and I don't know how to get rid of them.

For example, sometimes the string looks like: "xxx -2 *     4". Applying `gsub` and `strsplit` give me "-2" "*" "" "" "4". How do I get rid of those two white space in the middle?

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015866/extract-a-number-from-a-string-in-r/58015970#58015970

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to extract everything after `"new"` till a non-digit is encountered.

```
sub(".*new(.*)\\s+\\D.*", "\\1", x)
#[1] " * -2 5 4" " -2 5 6"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("something new * -2 5 4 else", "something new -2 5 6 other")
```